# Custom shape background - clipping of background not working

Tags: android, selector, shapes

I want to have a custom shape as background image of my items in in popup list view. But if I do this I see following problem:

[image]

I see a selector like background behind my custom shape. Why?

I tried setting `android:foreground="@null"` as I thought there is a foreground image set from anywhere, but this does not make a difference...

**Observations**

Adding `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"` to `llShortcutParent` results in correct background clipping. Why? This solves the simple problem of having the selector like background behind my own custom shape background, but I want to go a step further and replace the shape background with a selector, but this result in another problem:

If I use a selector, this trick does not work anymore, because then the selector does simply not work and only the default state background is drawn

So I'm stuck, I either have a working selector (if I remove the style) but have the default selector like background behind my own selector or I have a good looking view without a selector...

**Solutions**

- Simple solution, if no selector is used:

  `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"` solves this issue
- Solution that works with a selector as backgorund as well:

  ??? => no one found yet...

**Code**

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llShortcutParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shortcut_shape"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

My custom shape looks like following (`shortcut_shape.xml`)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFF"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new drawable and apply as

```
android:foreground="@drawable/circle.xml"
```

**circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/colorShadow"
        android:radius="38dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      android:shape="rectangle" >
 <corners android:radius="14dp"      />
 <gradient
 android:angle="45"
 android:centerX="35%"
 android:centerColor="#A83CA8"
 android:startColor="#A83CA8"
 android:endColor="#A83CA8"
 android:type="linear"
 />
 <padding
 android:left="0dp"
 android:top="0dp"
 android:right="0dp"
 android:bottom="0dp"
 />
 <size
 android:width="270dp"
 android:height="60dp"
 />
 <stroke
 android:width="3dp"
 android:color="#A83CA8"
 />
 </shape>
```

Apply this code